# Is there a good introduction to subjectivity in language?

Tags: semantics, linguistic-typology, philosophy-of-language, pragmatics, evidentiality

Since the topic of "subjectivity in language" is all new to me, I am looking for an introduction to the topic that 1) gives an overview of the phenomena usually associated with the topic (evidentiality? modality?) and/or 2) contains information on how subjectivity is expressed in different languages. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

A good introduction is Heiko Narrog's **Modality, subjectivity, and semantic change**. [This link](http://www.amazon.co.jp/Modality-Subjectivity-Semantic-Change-Cross-Linguistic/dp/0199694370/ref=sr_1_4?s=english-books&ie=UTF8&qid=1414051393&sr=1-4&keywords=narrog) accesses the Japanese amazon site, where you can, if you're quick, have a look inside. Just click on the picture of the book cover in the upper left corner.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll probably find [Alexandra Aikhenvald and her book on evidentiality](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Evidentiality-Alexandra-Y-Aikhenvald/dp/0199263884) a good starting point on the cross linguistic front.

But of course, subjectivity is much more complex than the associated morphosyntax. I think Ari Verhagen [cognitive linguistic treatment of Intersubjectivity](http://ukcatalogue.oup.com/product/9780199226702.do) addresses many important issues related to the semantics and pragmatics of subjectivity.